# Unable to edit value of custom formatter cell

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

After adding a text box to a column in my grid with a custom formatter, I am unable to select or change the text in any way after the grid renders. I don't want in-line editing, nor do I want to have the grid persist the changes back to the server, I simply want to be able to change the text of this column then let another action independent of the grid interrogate the the rows and update the server.

Thank you,
Stephen

GRID:

```
var favoriteGrid;
var colNames = ['Qty', 'Attributes', 'Item #', 'Brand', 'Product', 'Catalog', 'Price', 'UOM', 'Case', 'Remarks', 'Wt.', 'Par', 'Date', 'ProductId', '', 'CatalogId'];
var colModel = [
{ name: 'Quantity', index: 'Quantity', width: 22, formatter: quantityFormatter/*, editable:true, edittype:'text'*/ },
{ name: 'ProductAttributes', index: 'ProductAttributes', sortable: false, width: 50, title: false, formatter: productFormatter },
{ name: 'ItemNum', index: 'ItemNum', width: 50, align: "right" },
{ name: 'BrandName', index: 'BrandName', width: 100 },
{ name: 'ProducName', index: 'ProducName', width: 150 },
{ name: 'Catalog', index: 'Catalog', width: 100 },
{ name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: 40, sorttype: "number", align: "right" },
{ name: 'UOM', index: 'UOM', width: 30 },
{ name: 'CasePack', index: 'CasePack', width: 30 },
{ name: 'PackageRemarks', index: 'PackageRemarks', width: 80 },
{ name: 'AveWeight', index: 'AveWeight', width: 30, title: false, align: "right" },
{ name: 'Par', index: 'Par', width: 25, title: false, align: "right"},
{ name: 'LastPurchaseDate', index: 'LastPurchaseDate', width: 44, align: "right", formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm/d/Y'} },
{ name: 'ProductId', index: 'ProductId', hidden: true, key: true },
{ name: 'SortPriority', index: 'SortPriority', width: 20, sorttype: "number", align: "right" },
{ name: 'CatalogId', index: 'CatalogId', hidden: true }
 ];

function quantityFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<input type="text" class="qty-order" value="' + cellvalue + '" class="text" title="' + rowObject[13] + '" id="qty-' + rowObject[13] + '"/>';
};

function productFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) <Omitted...>

favoriteGrid = $('#favoriteGrid');

$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;

favoriteGrid.jqGrid({
    url: '/Buyer/Favorite/ItemsService/' + urlIndex,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    jsonReader: {
        id: "ProductId",
        cell: "",
        root: function (obj) { return obj.rows; },
        page: function () { return 1; },
        total: function () { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.rows.length; },
        repeatitems: true
    },
   /*        
    cellEdit: true,
    cellSubmit: null,
    cellurl: null,
   */
    colNames: colNames,
    colModel: colModel,
    pager: $('#favoritePager'),
    pginput: true,
    rowNum: 1000,
    autowidth: true,
    height: getProposedHeight(),
    sortable: true,
    multiselect: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    loadonce: true,
    loadui: 'block',
    emptyrecords: 'Nothing to display',
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid, e) {
        myClickHandle.call(this, rowid);
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        var gd = $('#favoriteGrid');
        fixGridSize(gd);

        /*var ids = favoriteGrid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');*/
    }
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#favoritePager',
    { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: false },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    { multipleSearch: true, showQuery: false },
    {}).jqGrid('sortableRows', {
        update: function (ev, ui) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you explain how you plan to change the values of the cells? You wrote that you don't want use any editing mode. Which methods you planed to use? Is it something like `setCell`, `setRowData` or you want change local data in `data` parameter and reload the grid? You wrote just "I simply want to be able to change the text of this column" without any details. More details is really required.

Comment: @Oleg, The end user would check-on the rows to be selected and modify the quantity cell (default of 1) if need be, then they'll click on another button (add to cart) located off the grid at which time I'll grab the necessary data to push back to the server for the beginning of a PO.

Comment: Something similar to this post example..http://permanaj.net/jqgrid/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least one problem in your current implementation of the custom formatter which you posted

```
function quantityFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<input type="text" class="qty-order" value="' + cellvalue +
               '" class="text" title="' + rowObject[13] +
               '" id="qty-' + rowObject[13] + '"/>';
}
```

The problem is that custom formatter can be called with **3 different formats** of `rowObject`.

You use `jsonReader: {cell: "", repeatitems: true, ...}`. So at the first load `rowObject` will be really array with the data (typically array of strings) which represent the row.

You use `loadonce: true`. So during the first loading of the grid internal `data` parameter will be filled. `data` will be array of items, but the items will be *objects* with properties like the column names (see `name` property in `colModel` items). If the user click for example on the column header the grid need be sorted and the grid body have to be refilled from local `data` parameter. In the case the custom formatter `quantityFormatter` will be called with `rowObject` which represent item of `data` and you have to use `rowObject.ProductId` instead of `rowObject[13]`.

If you would use `setCell` or `setRowData` to change the value of the column 'Quantity' the format of `rowObject` will be the third one (!!!???). [The line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.base.js#L3269) of `setCell` contains `ind` parameter which will be forwarded to custom formatter as `rowObject`. The `ind` will be set before in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.base.js#L3265):

```
var ind = $t.rows.namedItem(rowid);
```

So you will be have as `rowObject` DOM element which represent the row (`<tr>`). So to you should use something like `$(rowObject).find(">td:nth-child(13)").text()` instead of `rowObject[13]`.

To write common code you have to test the type of `rowObject`. For example

```
function quantityFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var productId = typeof rowObject.ProductId !== "undefined" ?
            rowObject.ProductId :
            (rowObject instanceof HTMLTableRowElement ?
                $(rowObject).find(">td:nth-child(13)").text() :
                rowObject[13]);
    return '<input type="text" class="qty-order text" value="' + cellvalue +
               ' title="' + productId + '" id="qty-' + productId + '"/>';
}
```

In your case you can simplify the above code because you have `key: true` in the `'ProductId'` and the id of the row will be the same as contain of `'ProductId'` column. The rowid is assigned in input parameter `options` in the `rowId` property. So you can rewrite your formatter implementation as following

```
function quantityFormatter(cellvalue, options) {
    var productId = options.rowId;
    return '<input type="text" class="qty-order text" value="' + cellvalue +
               ' title="' + productId + '" id="qty-' + productId + '"/>';
}
```

Now we don't use `rowObject` at all and it will work in all tree cases of calling of custom formatter.

Comment: Implemented new formatter, but still the same problem, unable to select the text of the input element.

Comment: OK, time for me to eat some crow. There seems to be an issue with Firefox 12 not letting me select the text, all other current browsers are working. Safari 5.1.2, Chrome 21 (Canary too) , and IE 9.. Thank you Dr.

Comment: @SPATEN: You are welcome! Now I am in time trouble, but later I will try to look at the problem in Firefox 12. Please, remind me next week if I forget about the problem.